# Shas Chazarah Seforim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Are there any seforim that are catered only to help one chazar mesechtos/Shas Bavli? If so, can you please direct me to them.

Comment: Not a sefer but nonetheless very helpful: http://dafyomi.co.il/main.php

Answer (score 2):

One series to aid in review of Bavli is called ‘Shinun HaShas’. I’ve seen it on multiple tractates but don’t know if it’s on the complete Bavli. It’s basically a summary of the *gemara’s* give-and-take.

Another book, but much older, serving to aid with review, was published in 1555 by [R. Ishmael HaCohen](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14242-tanuji-ishmael-ha-horen) ‘[Sefer HaZikaron](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/45028)’. He summarized the *halachic* elements of the Bavli, including pertinent views of Rashi and Tosafot. (In his intro. he writes that when he began writing the book he was unaware of [R. Jacob b. Asher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher)’s ‘Kitzur Piske Ha’Rosh’, an abridged work of his father’s, which served a similar purpose. Although he describes there why his own book is still beneficial in a few ways. In the beginning of the book he also provides a sort of index of what is discussed in each tractate.)

Comment: where can i buy this sefer hazikoron

Comment: @Moshe [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/EGYPTIAN-JUDAICA-CUSTOMS-Sefer-Hazikaron-Minhagim/392851626230?hash=item5b77c818f6:g:ZFgAAOSwkO5e9Ju7)

Answer (score 1):

[There is חזרת השס](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9_%D7%A1.html?id=jZa4swEACAAJ). Does as you described, I have a copy handy.

Comment: How do you view the link? @Dr.Shmuel?

Comment: Click it? (The link)

Comment: It says it's not available... @Dr.Shmuel

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel is that sefer on all of shas or is it by masechta?

Comment: I am familiar with it being in around five volumes @alicht

Comment: @alicht [Here’s](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-vol-set-CHAZARAT-HASHAS-on-Zeraim-Moed-Summary-of-Sugyot/392328514104?hash=item5b589a0a38:g:csEAAOSwk8xdHkub) Zeraim and Moed.

Comment: Yes, @alicht Oliver's ebay listing is what I was referring to.